# Prevent a particular table being modified in SQL by a particular user

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, database-permissions

As the title says, however i have tried everything to prevent a user from modifying this table with no luck

For some reason DENY do not exist in the mySQL 5.5 manual so the following doesn't work

```
DENY ALL ON OBJECT::database.table TO user
DENY ALL ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost'
REVOKE ALL ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost'
```

The last one gives me this error

```
There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host 'localhost' on table 'table'
```

However, if that was the case then would it not be able to Insert, Select or Update?

Any help is appreciated, i will add the system information below.

Software: MySQL

Software version: 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Protocol version: 10

Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot lock out a MySQL user from just one table. If they already have permissions to the whole database, you'll need to revoke that and regrant them access on the specific tables they **do** need to be able to touch.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your update statement to make use of the [`current_user()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) function:

```
update mytable set
...
where id = ?
and current_user() not in ('john', 'bob', 'sally')
```